# ¿Cómo puedo convertir sintácticamente un for en un while?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo convertir sintácticamente un for en un while?

```js
    for (var num = 1; num <= 10; num = num+1) {
     document.write ("Hola 10 veces<br/>");
    }
```

Comment: Hola Sarusky, bienvenida a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio y [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas. Has mirado la documentacion del `while en JS`?  Has intentado implementarlo? De ser así , ponlo  en tu pregunta para que podamos decirte qué tienes mal o cómo arreglarlo. Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es sacar la variable que usas de contador fuera e incrementarla despues de cada vuelta.

```js
/* FOR */

document.write ("BUCLE FOR <br/>");
document.write ("<br/>");

for (var num = 1; num <= 10; num = num+1) {
    document.write ("Hola 10 veces<br/>");
}
document.write ("<br/>");

/* WHILE */

document.write ("BUCLE WHILE <br/>");
document.write ("<br/>");

var i=1;
while(i<=10){
    document.write ("Hola 10 veces<br/>");
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias GDP!!

Comment: Si esta es la respuesta adecuada marcala con el tick ;)

Answer (score 1):

Un while es otra forma de hacer un bucle. Tienes que tener en cuenta 3 puntos:

1. El valor inicial de la variable, num en este caso y se declara fuera del bucle
2. La condición de salida.
3. Modification de la variable de la condición de salida.

El resultado seria:

```
var num = 1;
while ( num <= 10 ) {
  document.write ("Hola 10 veces<br/>");
  num++;
}
```

una vez que termina el while, num sigue teniendo valor ya que sigue estando dentro del ámbito. Si fuera un for, num se habría destruido al terminar el bucle

Comment: ¡¡Muchísimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer ese mismo bucle con un while seria asi:

```
var n = 1;

while(n < 11){
document.write("hola"+n+"vez<br>");
n++;
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: ¡¡Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Te ahorras una linea de código y algo de lógica de este modo:

```js
var num = 0;
while ( ++num < 11 ) {
  document.write ("Hola " + num + " veces<br/>");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!